# PHP mapping one array to another but with different key locations

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to map values in two arrays which have different shapes, as follows:

```
$array1=array(
    1=>array(1=>'apple', 2=>'banana', 3=>'cherry'),
    2=>array(1=>'david', 2=>'eddie', 3=>'frank'),
);
```

Now:

```
$array2=array(
    1=>'apple',
    2=>'banana',
    3=>'cherry',
    4=>'david',
    5=>'eddie',
    6=>'frank',
);
```

Such that when the value of $array1[2][3] is changed from `frank` to `paula` for example, then the value of $array2[6] is changed similarly.

How would I do this? NOTE: the keys will not change in quantity once declared.

Comment: If you want to keep the two array structures in sync, then you'll have to rebuild $array2 whenever $array1 changes. One *could* use references, but that would require manual array building. A virtual `ArrayObject` that automaps it might be another option.

Comment: @SunilPachlangia, array_merge will not sync things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the freedom to build the `$array2` in another way?
If you do, then this is how you can go about the 'linked' arrays:

```
<?php

$array1=array(
    1=>array(1=>'apple', 2=>'banana', 3=>'cherry'),
    2=>array(1=>'david', 2=>'eddie', 3=>'frank'),
);
$array2=array(
    1=>'apple',
    2=>'banana',
    3=>'cherry',
    4=>'david',
    5=>'eddie',
    // Assign by reference $array1[2][3] (currently holding 'frank')
    6=>&$array1[2][3],
);
// This will print the initial state of $array2
echo '<pre>';print_r( $array2 );echo '</pre>';
// Now change the value in $array1
$array1[2][3] = 'paula';
// And since $array2 'points' to the same memory location it will get
// changed too (well technically it won't but that's not important)
echo '<pre>';print_r( $array2 );echo '</pre>';
```

For more information about assignment by reference you can check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) out

Answer (score 1):

Please use array merge, here is how it will help you.

```
<?php
$a1=array("red","green");
$a2=array("blue","yellow");
print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));
?>
```

will output,

```
Array ( [0] => red [1] => green [2] => blue [3] => yellow )
```

to learn more, http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php


$array1=array(
    1=>array(1=>'apple', 2=>'banana', 3=>'cherry'),
    2=>array(1=>'david', 2=>'eddie', 3=>'frank'),
);
$op = array();

foreach($array1 as $key =>$index){
    $op =array_merge($array1[1],$array1[2]);
}

print_r(  $op);
?>
```

Use array_merge to merge two arrays

Comment: that is not very useful.  It is hard coded to 1 and 2, and merging wouldn't create an array which changes as the first one did.  @mrun post is correct.